# Trouble logging in with BlogSpot

Tags: authentication, openid, blogspot

This question belongs on meta. I'd ask there, but I need to log in to ask a question, and that's where my problem is :)

I have an ID on BlogSpot.com (that's the Google Blog thing). I'm pretty sure that's my credential for this here site. However, I can't use it to log in to superuser.com (where I originally wanted to go) although I have my user ID linked to there.

The problem is, When I try to log in with my BlogSpot ID (and correct password), I end up on a 404 page; end of the line.

Could somebody please take a look? I'd prefer to get an answer here or to carl dot smotricz @ gmail dot com, as I'm obviously unable to pick up answers on meta...

Comment: I get exactly the same problem using Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this gets solved by logging into Blogger in another tab (or browser window).  Once this is done it seems to work.